# Term lineage in simple Hierarchical select module

Tags: nodes, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm working on a project using Drupal 7. I'm using simple **Hierarchical select module**.

How its possible to attach the parent lineage to the node? Is there any way to do so using **simple Hierarchical select**? because the SHS only attach the child term to the node
I tried to google it million times but couldn't find an answer

I tried the Hierarchical select module but its doesn't help because I'm using this field as exposed filter in a view and there are only two 'selection type' choices:

- **Autocomplete** : Which is not what am not looking for
- **Drop down** : Which combines the parent terms and children terms in one list and that is not what I want , I want the selection type to be Hierarchical select which is not provided

please help
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

With views you can use [SHS](http://drupal.org/project/shs) which will provide simple Hierarchical select as selection type in expose filter.

To attach the parent term to node, you need to use the combination of [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds), Panels and [entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module with [token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token). 
You can use parent term's token in Display Suit of default layout or any you want to use.